# Does Redis lock during write?

Tags: redis

I tried to find out but I don't sure that is Redis MVCC?
Does Redis allow reading during writing?

Answer (score 10):

Redis is single-threaded. All commands are atomic. While command is running, no other command can be executed. But since everything is in memory, commands are (normally) pretty fast.

So no, redis does not allow reading during writing, but that's not a problem.

Comment: And of course Redis does not implement MVCC, because no lock is needed. Redis "transactions" are not executed in parallel, they are fully isolated (in the ACID sense).

Comment: ... and ACID isolation implies that after all data is fully committed, the results of parallel writes will be exactly the same as if these writes were run serially.

Comment: "So no, redis does not allow reading during writing, but that's not a problem." It is a huge problem, just saying =)

Comment: @Ted: yeah, I can see how it can be a problem in some setups. :) We can parallel-read from replicas, though.